# Sphinx autoflask only documents Flask's built-in static route

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx

I have a Flask app with multiple routes, but `.. autoflask:: myapp:app` only documents the `/static/` route.

In `docs/conf.py` I import `myapp` and `print myapp.app.url_map`.  It shows multiple routes.

```
Map([<Rule '/blah/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> blah>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> hello>,
 <Rule '/post/image/<post_id>' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> postimage>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>])
```

Most of my routes are in a separate import, so as a test I put the `blah` endpiont directly below the declaration of my app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route("/blah/")
def blah():
    return "tacos"
```

When I `make html` it only documents the `/static/` route.

```
GET /static/(path: filename)
    Function used internally to send static files from the static folder to the browser.
```

I am following the instructions laid out by the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/#sphinxcontrib-autohttp-flask-exporting-api-reference-from-flask-app), so I'm not sure what is going wrong.  Anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: Do your views have a docstring comment (first entry in the function being a string)?  The docs say "View functions that don’t have docstring (__doc__) are excluded by default. If this flag option has given, they become included also."